# Is there a complete list of meteor special directory names and what they do?

Tags: meteor, directory

Meteor checks directory names and treats javascript inside directories with special names differently. Some of the "magical" directory names that I know of are:

```
server
client
public
lib
startup
import
node_modules (I think, but I'm not sure)
```

This list keeps growing and it's getting confusing. Is there a consolidated list of this somewhere? If not, I guess I'll dig through the source and make one.

Edit: I guess I really want to know what filenames are special as well (server.js, client.js, startup.js). I hate the idea that I might name a file or directory something and it will affect the app behavior in unexpected ways.

Comment: They had a list of special directories in their docs, but now it seems they've changed the whole web page due to version 1.3

Comment: Did they take the 1.2 docs down!? Can't find them anywhere. I have a feeling that list wasn't complete either.

Comment: It seems they took the 1.2 docs down. I dunno why.. And it seems that the file structuring is different in 1.3 .. I'm not sure.

Comment: I found a snapshot of the 1.2 docs [here](http://devdocs.io/meteor/). Read the section called "Structuring your app"..it's at the beginning. It has all the information.

Comment: Good find. Might almost be complete. Missing "lib," and who knows what else. Isn't "startup" a special directory?

Comment: I've never encountered `startup/`, but `lib/` is mentioned in the docs under "File Load Order". Basically, the only reason for using `lib/` is because it is loaded first. Also, if you want to load a file last, then make its name start with `main.`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** The Meteor Guide has been updated and now contains 1.2 and 1.3 style load order and special directory information [Here](http://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#load-order)

server - Only ran on the server
client - Only sent to the client
client/compatibility - Loaded first before other normal javascript files, put jquery, bootstrap etc here if you're having issues with them elsewhere
public - Static files/assets such as images,music etc available to user
public/online - a folder that won't be cached if configed to
private - Static files/assets only available to the server
imports - Files only loaded when using an import command.
node_modules - used by NPM for node modules, is separate from meteor.
tests - Files for tests - not loaded anywhere else.
lib - loaded on both clients, loaded prior to other code

Any other folder (that I am aware of) is not a special folder but is loaded by both server and client. Startup is not special but is a convention used by developers to state that the files within pertain to the startup of the app, such as config files or fixtures data.

You could use any folder name you wanted that isn't treated specially and it will be loaded on both server and client.

The recommended way to use Meteor now is to use the imports directory and only import code when and where you need it to control the flow and load order.

It is annoying that they removed this list from the Meteor Docs. One of the commenters found a link to the old docs: http://devdocs.io/meteor/index#structuringyourapp
**Update**: Link now points to new meteor guide.

Comment: Getting there... I think you forgot the "compatibility" directory. Somebody really needs to check the source because it's becoming increasingly clear to me that nobody knows what all the secret magic directories are. I had a quick look but couldn't find where they are defined. Also is "online" really a special directory??

Comment: @foobarbecue - Good point - I've updated my answer to reflect that as well as link to the updated meteor guide.

Comment: Excellent. Their docs are much better now. It's almost like someone over there read this!

Comment: It's exactly like that :)  https://forums.meteor.com/t/stackoverflow-questions-the-really-need-an-answer/20403

Comment: Argh, they [added more special file names in 1.3](http://guide.meteor.com/1.3-migration.html#breaking-changes): "Files within your app named *.test[s].*, *.app-test[s].*, *.spec[s].* and *.app-spec[s].* will no longer load eagerly (you should probably rename such a file if it doesn’t contain tests, as it will be eagerly loaded by our new app testing modes)."

Answer (score 1):

The new directory structure for Meteor 1.3 is documented at http://guide.meteor.com/structure.html

Comment: Yes, but the guide does not have a complete list of meteor special directory names.